# Check if entry is already done

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am looking for a smarter way to check if a text in a record already exists.
Basically I wrote a database which stores minutes.
Since only the latest information should be stored in a textbox (there the entries are made) and "old" information goes to a history box I am looking for a way to prevent double entries in this history box.

For that reason I used the InStr Function to check if the the first 10 letters already exists in the history field it doesn't add the information. I start at position 100 since there is this header I made to differ between the entries.
Actually it works most the times but I could not figure out why it doesn't add information many times then this information is actually new so I look for a smarter way or does somebody see a mistake?

```
Private Sub txt_Comments_W9_LostFocus()
 ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
 ' History function.
 ' Since only the latest information should be stored at the text field the old/other     information will be stored at the history box
 ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim temp As String
Dim newComment As String
Dim Version As String

temp = " "
newComment = " "

Version = "<b>" & "****************************************" & "Version " & Date & ": " & "****************************************" & "</b>"
newComment = Version & txt_Comments_W9.Value


If Len(Nz(txt_History_W9.Value)) = 0 Then
    If Len(Nz(txt_Comments_W9.Value)) = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        txt_History_W9.Value = "<div>" & newComment & "<BR>"
    End If
Else
    temp = txt_History_W9.Value
    If InStr(100, temp, Mid(txt_Comments_W9.Value, 1, 10)) = 0 Then
        txt_History_W9.Value = "<div>" & temp & newComment & "<BR>"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `Len(Nz(txt_History_W9.Value))` returns 0 you will skip the check after your else. Is that on purpose?

Also, is there a reason why you are using `Mid(txt_Comments_W9.Value, 1, 10)` instead of `Left(txt_Comments_W9.Value, 10)`.

And if the arguments for Instr are as follows: `InStr([start,]string1,string2[,compare])`, It can return:

```
If string1 is "" - InStr returns 0
If string1 is Null - InStr returns Null
If string2 is "" - InStr returns start
If string2 is Null - InStr returns Null
If string2 is not found - InStr returns 0
If string2 is found within string1 - InStr returns the position at which match is found
If start > Len(string1) - InStr returns 0
```

Make sure you know what the InStr Function returns in case of no match.

Answer (score 0):

The way this table is Structured is very odd. Your table design should ideally be something like.

```
tbl_MinutesHistory
------------------
minID   |   minDate     |   minEntree   |   minNotes
--------+---------------+---------------+--------------------------------
1       |   03/04/2014  |   Paul        |   Meeting for Boss birthday
2       |   05/05/2014  |   Eugin       |   Meeting to elect new boss
3       |   02/06/2014  |   Francis     |   Company shutting down meeting
```

Then your history box (I guess it is a Listbox) would include everything except the last date. Rowsource would be something like

```
SELECT minDate, minEntree, minNotes
FROM tbl_MinutesHistory
WHERE minID Not In (SELECT Max(minID) As maxOfID FROM tbl_MinutesHistory);
```

You are making things more complicated with code !

Comment: Hi PaulFrancis, the text isn't stored as a Listbox. It is a simple textbox right under the current textbox where the stuff is added to. Since there are only a few sentences which get added every meeting and to get a quick overview.

Comment: Even better, you do not have a lot to fluff around then. Just reorganize our table as shown, then you can work with that very easily. This is my opinion.